# Selecting next element of the parent

Tags: html, jquery, checkbox, jquery-selectors

This is my coding,

```
<tr class="ar">
   <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="cbx">
   </td>    
   <td>
        <span class="spc">book</span>
   </td> 
</tr>
<tr class="ar"></tr>
```

What I want to do, if checkbox or span is clicked (inside first `tr`), I want to toggle a class to the second `tr`. Also if the checkbox is already checked, then I need to uncheck when clicking any of these.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: How many <tr> there? Whether you want kind of radio button functionality for check box's.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('td input[type=checkbox], td span').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr')
        .find('input[type=checkbox]')
        .prop("checked", false)
        .end()
        .next()
        .toggleClass('yourclass');
});
```

Comment: This will get next `td` not `tr`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$(".cbx2").click(function(){
  $(this).closest("tr.ar").next().toggleClass("toggled_class");
});
```

`$(this).closest("tr.ar")` will give you the closest parent `tr` element of this object with `ar` class and `.next` will get next element of that kind which is your second `tr`.

Comment: You want `closest()` here instead of `parents()`, it's unnecessary to travel all the way up the DOM and potentially coming across another element with the class of `ar`

Comment: @TimJoyce: Yep, closest is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.... if you want to uncheck the checkbox...

```
$('#your_checkbox_id').live('click' , function() {
    if($('#your_checkbox_id').is(':checked')) {
        $('#your_checkbox_id').removeAttr('checked');
        $(this).next().toggleClass('class_name');
    }
});
```

Comment: You don't need to repeatedly use the same selector. Just use `this`. Also, `live` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.cbx, .spc').click(function(e){
    $('.cbx').prop('checked', false); // uncheck everything

    $(this).toggleProp(checked, $(this).prop('checked')) // check/uncheck current
           .closest('.ar').toggleClass('yourClass'); // toggle class on next tr
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this one:http://jsfiddle.net/kPJJf/

```
$('td input[type=checkbox], td span').click(function () {
       $(this).parents('tr').next('tr').find('span').toggleClass('spc');
   if($(this).parents('tr').next('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')==false){
      $(this).parents('tr').next('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
   }else{
      $(this).parents('tr').next('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('checked');
   }
});
```